# How to change length of blue line in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, lengths

I am writing my cv using `moderncv`; I come across to this automatic correction where sentences are split in 2 lines like so:

[image]

What I would like to do is setting "Birth Date and Place" in the same line and extending the blue line accordingly.

Can you tell me what should I do?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,'roman']
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english]{babel}                  
\usepackage{microtype}                     
%\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\moderncvstyle{classic}                                                                 
\moderncvcolor{blue}                        
%\nopagenumbers{}                            
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}            
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}          
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}     

\begin{document}
\section{Personal Information}
\cvitem{Birth Date and Place}{February 7, 1698; Lovere, Como, Giamaica.}
\cvitem{Address}{via pinco~20/b, Pallo Figa, Cazzo, Italy}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should adjust `\hintscolumnwidth` to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
% Set width of "hints column" to match width of "Birth Date and Place"
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\hintscolumnwidth}{Birth Date and Place}}
\firstname{Firstname}
\lastname{Lastname}
\begin{document}
\section{Personal Information}
\cvitem{Birth Date and Place}{February 7, 1698; Lovere, Como, Giamaica.}
\cvitem{Address}{via pinco~20/b, Pallo Figa, Cazzo, Italy}
\end{document}
```

The setting of `\hintscolumnwidth` is delayed until the beginning of the document, where fonts are properly set.